# Editing Custom UIView Subclasses in Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

I have an application that uses a UIScrollView to page between a number of dynamically generated UIViews. Right now, I have to programmatically set the layout and ui elements of these UIViews, but I was wondering if there is any way to edit the interface of a subclass of UIView in storyboard (independent of a view controller).

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Just for reference, I'm using Xcode 4.2 with iOS 5.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### UPDATE

As of Xcode 7, you can edit a standalone view in a storyboard. Drag a view from the Object Library to the header bar of a view controller. Interface Builder will show the standalone view separately on the canvas above the view controller's main view. Example:

[image: standalone view in storyboard]

You will probably want to create an outlet from your view controller to the standalone view. The standalone view will only be accessible from the view controller that contains it.

Note that you get one instance of the standalone view when you load the view controller. If you need multiple instances, there's no particularly good way to get them.

### ORIGINAL

There is no convenient way to do this in a storyboard.

You can still create nibs in a project that uses a storyboard.  So you can create a nib for each view, and load them from your code:

```
NSString *nibName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"page%d", pageNumber];
NSArray *nibObjects = [NSBundle.mainBundle loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil];
UIView *pageView = [nibObjects objectAtIndex:0];
CGSize size = self.scrollView.bounds.size;
pageView.frame = CGRectMake(pageNumber * size.width, 0, size.width, size.height);
[self.scrollView addSubview:pageView];
```

Comment: Thanks! I've never used nib files before, but this seems to make perfect sense for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: 1)If I create UICollectionViewCell do I need to register it or I can directly use it??

Comment: 2) I generally use xib if I need same view in two controllers or places. Can we associate one view in storyboard with two controllers?

Comment: 1. You need to register it, but it would be simpler to use the storyboard's existing support for designing collection view cells directly inside the collection view. 2. No, in that case you might want to keep using a separate XIB, or you could use view controller containment (maybe via an embed segue).

Comment: Does this have any compatibility issues with earlier iOS versions ?

Comment: @robmayoff I have a question related to the XCode 7 demo that you attached. I did the same as you on the demo and I added outlet to this view, but I don't see on top of my view when I run the app. Can you advice how can I show it? Thanks!

Comment: @robmayoff I have added it. I just dragged the whole extra view inside the old view. Thanks! (I am using Xcode 7)

Comment: Oh I think I understand. Just adding the external view in the storyboard doesn't do anything to make the view show up at runtime. It's up to you to add the external view to your view hierarchy at runtime. (That's why you need the outlet connected to the external view, so you have a reference you can use to add it as a subview of some on-screen view.)