# Swift Storyboard nested view

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I am trying to add separate view (which I want to populate with few some icarousel element - but I don't want to occupy whole page for it.

That view should be inside of the view controller. But, as I am trying I can't add more than one view to the view controller.

Can someone advice how then should I separate this "nested" view from the main view and how to add it through storyboard?

I tried to find working demo or similar, but unsuccessfully.

Can someone advice how this should be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9320168/77567

Comment: I think that should be it! Thanks! Please write it as answer, so I can accept it! Thanks a lot!!